# checked list box text + value

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

Hi how to retrieve checked list box value in win forms application using c# ?

just like in asp.net li.selectedvalue and li.selectedtext

is there any methods like this to get value and text individually?

Regards,
Nagu

Answer (score 1):

[SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem.aspx) is the closest to what you're looking for, but since it's an object you have to cast it to the type of the items you put in the listbox to get additional properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [CheckedListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx) control, you have the [CheckedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems.aspx) property.